# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException but i used AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with my class who use a http connection. The error is for the connection, i read that error mean that i have to use the AsyncTask, but i used it and my app still doesn't work.
Here there is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    new GetCoursesDetails().execute();
}
class GetCoursesDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InfoCorsi.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading courses details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_info_corsi, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single course Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_COURSES); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);



                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The class jSONParser work because i used it to make a connection for another class, the error in this case is of the type android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException:

```
1-18 13:44:46.478 23304-23318/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.piemonteorientale.cus.cuspo, PID: 23304
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.piemonteorientale.cus.cuspo.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.piemonteorientale.cus.cuspo.InfoCorsi$GetCoursesDetails$1.run(InfoCorsi.java:89)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-18 13:44:53.635 23304-E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Read before you jump in and implement.

Comment: post the JSONParser class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `runOnUiThread()` from your `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: hi , I was checking this [asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts/17583324#17583324) for levit user about internet connection if there is internet, there is some problems with `ping` in some devices as comments stated, I want your help to know if you have an already answer , if no ill post it . do you think levit a best practice to apply on my app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your progress you can use `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate (Progress...)`. This method will run on the UI Thread. Don't make any network calls from it. Use `AsyncTask.publishProgress (Progress...)` from your `AsyncTask.doInBackground (Params...)` method to invoke the progress update.

See [AsyncTask API Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)